# Self instantiating properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

It it possible to have a getter property in TypeScript that replaces itself with an instance property. I have a class with lots of metadata properties and most instances wont call them so I only want to create an instance if they are needed but I also don't want to be calling a property with checking logic for every call after the object has been instantiated.

Something like the following snippet but strongly typed

```js
let obj = {
  get prop() {
    delete this.prop;
    console.log('Creating instance');
    this.prop = { data: 'Here is the data' };
    return this.prop;
  }
};

console.log(obj.prop.data);

console.log(obj.prop.data);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I would look for another way to do this. This kind of magic and indirection is why Ruby/Rails are so painful to work with, and why they're so dangerous to use and refactor.

Comment: "*but strongly typed*" - what is the problem with the current code?

Comment: Also, you speak of a `class`, but the example snippet shows an object literal? The solution would probably be quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is with [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), along with manually typing the getter.

```js
const obj = {
  get prop():{data: string} {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'prop', {
        value: { data: 'Here is the data' }
    });
    return this.prop;
  }
};

console.log(obj.prop);
```

You can see this typechecks [on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGBzAprAA4BOIRAFAJQBc6AJgIZSM0zQkCWYuAvhthwwA8knzAoAOnr4AZt3wAFMkXwkoATwpQAFpwgAaGAHJS5Y0axDrMAG6MANgFd8bdDCYs2xgBJr8MPowugGejMYwvII4vFQA3NEwJIROJGDBehCSZkQJMZi8CZigkCAO+JIOILgUCIjZKvGYQA).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yjkgpk?file=index.ts%3AL20 works exactly as I was hoping it would, thanks.